# AWS Lambda & API Gateway

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

Currently, I have a monolithic application that we want to port to server less microservices using lamba. How it works now is that there is only one endpoint `http://localhost:3000/input?data=%7Btype%3A%27music%27%2Cname%3A%27Sorry%27%3A%2Cartist%3A%27justin%20bieber%27%7D`. Based on the content of data parameter (regex evaluation on message attribute) then we know which portion of the code to call. (ie. music, video, picture processor). If we are to break up the monolith into 3 lambda functions how can we use API gateway to trigger these functions based on the data query string?

Note: The client side is out of our control and it is a blackbox that can only call 1 url in the format above. the data parameter is a url encoded json string.

What is the best approach? We were considering writing a standalone application that would proxy the request to the API/Lambda but this will not be serverless (may have to use a EC2). The other option is to trigger a lambda function that would decode the data parameter, perform the regex then invoke the appropriate lambda.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how we solved the problem similar to this.

> CloudFront --> API GW --> Lambda (Analyze Parameters & Make call to
>   the right endpoint) --> Http external call

This is a simple and scalable approach.

If your origin needs failover capability, you can create Origin Group with CloudFront and host lambda in a different region and make it highly available.

Hope it helps.

Comment: so you are proposing to use the second option that I mentioned above? If so, this is what we are leaning towards but if there is a best practice approach out there then we would love to see it too.

Comment: You have confused with EC2 or servers. It can be purely serverless.

Comment: why do you say there is a confusion?

Comment: Maintaining servers are old technology.

Comment: You are write but I did not say anything about maintaining servers. I said have and EC2 with an app that does the proxying. however, that wasn't the option that I chose.